# Whats the difference between React render and React-DOM render

Tags: reactjs

EDITED because my original question was not worded right.

I'm trying to understand why ReactDOM is being used to render some HTML divs, and other rendering is done in React. Is there something I'm missing here?

An example from a React course I took recently, this is the code in one of the exercises that uses react-dom:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'

var Bookstore = [
  {"title":"Mr. Bean", "author":"Rowan Atkinson", "pages":200},
  {"title":"The only Bean", "author":"Chris Dowd", "pages":100},
  {"title":"IT crowd", "author":"Rich Ayando", "pages":50}
]


const Book = ({title, author, pages}) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <h3>By {author}</h3>
      <p>{pages} pages</p>
    </section>
  )
}


const Library = ({bookstore}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {bookstore.map(
        (book, i) => <Book key={i} title={book.title} author={book.author} pages={book.pages}/>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}


render(
  <div>
    <Library bookstore={Bookstore} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

While another React file renders this way:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export const Book = ({title="No title", author="No author", pages=0, freeBookmark}) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <h3>By {author}</h3>
      <p>{pages} pages</p>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: "run into many code samples that use React-DOM to replace a DOM div instead of rendering the component from React", you should show those examples, otherwise your question seems too broad (except `render`, I've never seen such examples)

Comment: good point @DennisVash I updated my question. Like you said the `render` is the prime example used by React-DOM, but I dont see what the advantages are of rendering with react-dom over just a react component. I feel like I'm missing something here...  thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't understand the question: you're describing two different things? The DOM render is the bit that (unsurprisingly) renders the React app into the active DOM, nesting its resultant DOM inside the preexisting DOM element you specify in the `render()` function. Updating props/state, on the other hand, is what you do _internally_ in your app component tree. It has nothing to do with the DOM, or HTML, it has everything to do with React's virtual document object.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans my question is why import React-DOM to render the element when i could just render it with just React and then place the React element in the HTML...  see my example above, I'm trying to understand when/why I'd use  React-DOM rendering. Thanks!

Comment: Because you can't? React itself _does not have_ DOM rendering capabilities. That's literally why the ReactDOM library exists: to do that final step that makes sure React's virtual document object get mapped to a true web DOM for inclusion into a browser document. While there is no reason to wrap `<Library ... />` in an extra div component, you _do_ need ReactDOM's `render()` if you want to have a React app running as part of a web page.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ah, okay i get it now. i was confusing the rendering in components with the rendering to the DOM. thanks for explaining it. If you wish to post as answer I will accept it. Or if you think my question was too silly let's delete it :-) Either way thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What happens in the real DOM ?

> Each time something in the DOM changes. Since DOM is represented as a
>   tree structure, changes to the DOM is pretty quick but the changed
>   element, and it’s children’s has to go through Reflow/Layout stage and
>   then the changes have to be Re-painted which are slow. Therefore more
>   the items to reflow/repaint, slower your app becomes.

To overcome this react uses **virtual DOM**

### How virtual DOM helps?

> it tries to minimize these two stages to get better performance.
>   **virtual** means a representation of a UI is kept in memory and synced with the "real" DOM by a library such as ReactDOM.

### Difference between **render** in the component & **reactDOM.render** ?

> - Render in the component is used to construct the virtual DOM.
> - reactDOM.render is used to attach the virtual DOM tree to the real DOM tree after the diffing algorithm detects the changes.